# expected value of a log-normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with log-normal distribution, i.e.
> $$
> f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
>     \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\log x)^2}, & \text{for x>0} \\
>     0, & \text{otherwise}. \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Determine the value of $A=\sqrt{2\pi}\mathbb{E}[|\log X|]$.

I know that generally, $\mathbb{E}[X]=e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$. And in this case, $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$. My question is how do I apply this to $\mathbb{E}[|\log X|]$?

Comment: Try using the definition of $\mathbb{E}[F(X)]$, which is $\int_0^\infty F(x) f_X(x) dx$.
In this case the function is $F(X) = |log X|$.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), you want to compute
$$
A = \sqrt{2\pi}\mathbb{E}[|\log X|] = \sqrt{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty |\log x| f_X(x)dx
= \int_{0}^\infty \frac{|\log x|}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x}dx
$$
*(first step: you should have checked the integral converges. Shouldn't be more than a formality.)*

Now, to get rid of the absolute value, you can rewrite this as
$$\begin{align}
A &= \int_{0}^1 \frac{\log\frac{1}{x}}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2\frac{1}{x}}dx
+ \int_{1}^\infty \frac{\log x}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x}dx\\
&= 2\int_{1}^\infty \frac{\log x}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x}dx
\end{align}$$
the second equality by the change of variables $u=\frac{1}{x}$ in the first integral. Now, do the change of variables $t=\log x$ to get
$$\begin{align}
A &= 2\int_{1}^\infty \frac{\log x}{x} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log^2 x}dx
&= 2\int_{0}^\infty t e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}dt
\end{align}$$
since $dt = \frac{dx}{x}$. But now, we know how to solve this! Either you recognize $\sqrt{2\pi}\mathbb{E}[|Y|]$ for $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$; or you just notice that the integrand is a derivative, and you get
$$\begin{align}
A &= 2\left[-e^{-t^2/2}\right]_0^\infty = \boxed{2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=\log(X)=g(X)$ [Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar)

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(g^{-1}(y))}{|g'(g^{-1}(y))|}=\frac{f_X(e^y)}{e^{-y}}=\frac{\frac{1}{e^y\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y)^2}}{e^{-y}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 y^2}$$

which is a standard normal. (That's precisely why $X$ is lognormal!).

Then $$E[|Y|]= 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty y e^{-\frac12 y^2} dy =2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} du = 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Hence $$\sqrt{2\pi}\mathbb{E}[|\log X|]=2$$